# Frame/grid don't clear themselves when updated

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I tried to build a calendar which shows current month of the year, and by pressing << and >> buttons, one can see the previous or next month.
Code seems to work at first sight, but when you want to see the previous/next months, the frame doesn't clear itself completely, and shows the residual days form the previous months, like 31 for months which only has 30 days. 
I couldn't figure out how to remove them. Can you guys please help me? thanks

```
from tkinter import Tk, RAISED, Label, Button, Frame

class org(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.pack()


    def organizer(self, xx, yy):

        from calendar import monthrange, month
        monthname = str()
        m = month(yy, xx)

        for i in m:
            if i == '\n':
                break
            monthname +=i

        previous = Button(self, text = '<<', command = self.prev)
        previous.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        nextt = Button(self, text = '>>', command = self.ntt)
        nextt.grid(row = 0, column = 6)

        month = Label(self, text = monthname+ '   ')
        month.grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 5)

        labels = ['Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su']
        for i in range(len(labels)):
            days = Label(self, text = labels[i], width = 3)
            days.grid(row = 1, column = i)

        (startday, endday) = monthrange(yy, xx)


        r = 2

        for i in range(0,startday):
            label = Label(self, width=3, text='       ')
            label.grid(row = 2, column = i)

        for i in range(1, endday+1):
            label = Button(self, text = i, width = 3)
            label.grid(row = r, column = startday)
            startday +=1
            if startday > 6:
                startday -= 7
                r += 1

        for i in range(startday, 7):
            label = Label(self, width=3, text='       ')
            label.grid(row = r, column = i)



class Cal(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        self.x = 10  #Oct
        self.y =2016 #2016

        org.organizer(self,self.x, self.y)

    def prev(self):
        Frame.grid_remove(self)
        self.x -= 1
        if self.x==0:
            self.x = 1
        else:
            org.organizer(self,self.x, self.y)


    def ntt(self):
        self.x += 1
        if self.x==13:
            self.x = 12
        else:
            org.organizer(self,self.x, self.y)

root = Tk()
a = Cal(root)
a.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to remove all the widgets drawn on Tk() and redraw it. You can delete all widgets with the following code:

```
for child in root.winfo_children():
    child.destroy()
```